# Automatic Weights not working when trying to bend a cylinder

Tags: armature, transforms, pose-mode

I've been trying to add automatic weights to a cylinder to bend it at a 90 degree angle around the middle.
I've created the armature and then selected the cylinder and the armature and used add automatic weights. But in pose mode any rotation fails to mutate the cylinder.

Please find attached blender file link and images of my attempts.
[image: Cylinder Image]
[image: Cylinder in Question in the Scene Collection]

[Blender Source File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nm2um-oNq9vpyGmJE6z_O5X2gn6nRGcm/view?usp=sharing)

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need a topology that will allow your cylinder to bend, if it doesn't exist, it won't be able, so create at least one edge loop at its middle, and probably more. Also, deparent the armature from the cylinder before parenting the cylinder to the armature, otherwise there will be a parenting loop.

[image]