# Parent With Automatic Weights Not Working Correctly

Tags: armature, bones

I found some weird behavior. I have an armature with 3 connected bones with IK and have 1 geometry leg object which contains 3 cuboids, 2 icospheres, 1 cylinder. For some reason the cylinder does not get included in any vertex group when i parent the whole leg geometry object to the armature with Automatic Weights. I also tried to clear the parent and removed the armature modifier and deleted all vertex groups from the geometry object then parented it again with automatic weights to armature but still get the same result where the cylinder gets left behind. Well i could manually assign the cylinder to the bone.001 vertex group and it will work but that's a workaround. I must be missing something very important? I have a file attached https://pasteall.org/blend/03860b5705914c1fa9c1a62fa2cf01a4

[image]

PS: This time adding a loop cut or alot of geometry does not work. See how they get left behind or the cylinders partly move along. What could be the cause of this? Any workarounds? I attached the file at https://pasteall.org/blend/cb2f0f6e7278416f97b8a6d6e1738a0b

[image]

Comment: give some subdivision to the cylinder works,it seems amature don't recognize it.

Comment: nice that workaround works, i gave it 1 loop cut in the center and now it recognizes it, thanks man! something i will need to remember though. maybe i should report this as a bug?

Comment: I don't thinks it's a bug,it's common setting.

Comment: might be related to this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229799/automatic-weights-not-working-when-trying-to-bend-a-cylinder but it doesn't make sense because the cuboids don't even have a loop cut but they still are recognized and get added to armature. something about the cylinder is weird XD

Comment: @NatureK hey mate. can you help me out? this time the loop cut workaround doesn't work. Even adding alot of subdivisions did not work.

Comment: if automatic weight doesn't work, manual weight is always an option

Comment: yeah. sad though.

Comment: Firstly, your cylinder are all not subdivided,you should check it again.Secondly, I don't know how you model the ball,it's hard to seperate them,it seems that your ball are related to cylinder,that's maybe the source of problem.

Comment: the first encircled cylinder IS subdivided with alooooot of divisions. the cylinders got incorrectly assigned to a different bone. it's different problem not related to subdivisions. anyway it looks like a bug, the only known workaround solution is to manually assign the vertices to the group as @josephhansen has pointed out. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround: add 1 loop cut to the cylinder mesh. thank you @NatureK. Or manually add the vertices to their respective vertex groups